# Algorithm for Eigenvalues/ Eigenvectors calculation in Eigen library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, eigen

Please I want to know the "Eigen C++ Library" uses which **algorithm** for the calculation of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a complex matrix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the documentation, the simple case seems to use Schur decomposition:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html#a38d032b75b3e75640e3db42e7ab20c24